# Moq return value for object using Mock.of?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I need to mock the return value of a method in an object. I have something like this:

```
var mock = Mock.Of<IExample>( x => x.GetAll() == new List<IOtherExample>()) ;
```

but I get an error. If I use GetAll as property instead it works:

```
var mock = Mock.Of<IExample>( x => x.GetAll == new List<IOtherExample>()) ;
```

I know I can do this using new Mock, Setup and Return like this:

```
mock.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).Returns(new List<IOtherExample>());
```

but I would like to learn how to do this using Mock.Of.

The error looks something like this:

```
 Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' of method 'Moq.Language.Flow.IReturnsResult' Returns(System.Collections.Generic.IList)'
```

Again keep in mind that it works if GetAll is a property.

Thank you.

```
public interface IExample : IGenericExample<IOtherExample>
{

}

public interface IGenericExample<T>
{
   IList<T> GetAll()
}
```

Comment: Maybe if you'd pasted a complete code sample that would help, trying a simple but similar thing in LINQPad worked for me. I guess that `x = ...` is a typo since it should be `x => ...`.

Comment: I have added what the interfaces look like. Other than that no more code seems relevant. I fixed the typo you mentioned. The LINQ expression is valid as it compiles. It fails during run time.

Answer (score 2):

Can't post this as a comment due to code formatting:

```
void Main()
{   
    var t = Mock.Of<IExample>(x => x.GetAll() == new List<IOtherExample>());
    t.GetAll().Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public interface IOtherExample
{
}

public interface IExample : IGenericExample<IOtherExample>
{

}

public interface IGenericExample<T>
{
   IList<T> GetAll();
}
```

This works in my LINQPad, I'm using Moq 4.0. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

```
var example = Mock.Of<IExample>();
Mock.Get(example).Setup(x => x.GetAll()).Returns(new List<IOtherExample>());
```

That said, I think `Mock.Of<>` is a little semantically backwards. It communicates that the returned object *has* a mock compared to `new Mock<>` which returns an mock object that has a real instance.

I find this setup to be more meaningful than the snippet above.

```
var exampleMock = new Mock<IExample>();
exampleMock.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).Returns(new List<IOtherExample>());
```

Later, when the instance is needed to pass as an argument or for an assertion, using `exampleMock.Object` is simple enough.